# Let $K\subseteq X$. If $K$ is closed in the weak topology, then $K$ is closed in the norm topology.

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently reading through a functional analysis text, namely over the weak topology. In the text, the author states the following:

> **Claim 1**: Let $K\subseteq X$. If $K$ is closed in the weak topology, then $K$ is closed in the norm topology.

However, I don't see why this is true, unless convergence in the norm topology implies convergence in the weak topology. Under this assumption, here is my proof of the claim:

> *Proof*. Let $K\subseteq X$ be closed in the weak topology. To show $K$ is closed in the norm topology, we need to take a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ with $x_n\to x$ in norm, and show that $x\in K$. However, $x_n\to x$ in norm implies $x_n\to x$ in the weak topology. Therefore, we have a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$ with $x_n\to x$ in the weak topology. Since $K$ is closed in the weak topology, $x\in K$.

Again, this is fine, given that convergence in the norm topology implies convergence in the weak topology. Here is my proof of this:

> *Proof*. Suppose $x_n\to x$ in norm, i.e., $\|x_n-x\|\to0$. Take any $f\in X^*$. Notice by linearity, boundedness, and $\|x_n-x\|\to0$
> $$
> 0\leq|f(x_n)-f(x)|=|f(x_n-x)|\leq C\|x_n-x\|\to0.
> $$
> Therefore $f(x_n)\to x$. By definition this means $x_n\to x$ in the weak topology.

---

My question really is: is everything written correct?

Comment: yes, is correct.

Comment: @daw: Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Typo: $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.